# ASP.NET Core : Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, hosting

I have hosted asp.net core 2.1 web application on ubantu 18.04.3 LTS.

I am getting `Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.` error

Error source is `System.Private.CoreLib`

Stack trace is

`at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method) at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, Object target) at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CreateDelegate() at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda) at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression 1.Compile(Boolean preferInterpretation) at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression 1.Compile() at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.GetExecutor(MethodInfo methodInfo, TypeInfo targetTypeInfo) at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor..ctor(MethodInfo methodInfo, TypeInfo targetTypeInfo, Object[] parameterDefaultValues) at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Create(MethodInfo methodInfo, TypeInfo targetTypeInfo, Object[] parameterDefaultValues) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcAttributeRouteHandler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<RouteAsync>b__0(HttpContext c) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.ResponseCachingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)`

For your information I have developed and published my web application from `Visual Studio Code` and for publish I have used `dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish` command.

For local environment it is working fine. I am getting above error only on hosting environment.

Please assist me to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: Did you develop (and build) on a Windows machine?

Comment: Yes @Métoule I have developed and built that app on windows machine

Answer (score 0):

You encounter your issue because you built on a Windows machine, and thus what's published is not compatible with a Linux runtime.

To fix your issue, you need to specify that your app can target multiple runtimes, then specify which runtime to target when building your projects, with the [`--runtime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#arguments) flag. Without this flag, the executable only targets the current platform.

You can read more about the runtime identifiers on [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

**In your csproj:**

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

**dotnet tools:**

```
dotnet publish -c Release --runtime linux-x64 -o ./publish
```

Comment: Hi @Métoule 
getting same error for that solution as well